# Would my fridge magnet drop off on a non-magnetic planet?

Tags: electromagnetism

As far as I understand, the magnetic power of an ordinary permanent ferromagnet comes from and is maintained by the motion of molten iron in the Earth's core. So a fridge magnet would eventually come loose if no longer in contact with this source of replenishment due to the energy expenditure involved in constantly overcoming the force of gravity. Right?

Answer (score 5):

No. Permanent magnets works just as well on Mars or out in space.

Some permanent magnets might have gotten their powers due to the natural magnetic field of the Earth. Magnetite rocks (lodestones) got their magnetic properties this way.

However, they keep their magnetic property after they are removed from the magnetic field that caused them to magnetize. Actually this phenomena is used by geologists to investigate the history of Earth's magnetic field. [See an article on this from the University of Minnesota.](http://www.esci.umn.edu/courses/1001/minerals/magnetite.shtml)

Most of the permanent magnets to see today are made artificially out of special alloys often containing rare earth metals such as samarium or neodymium. They are treated with a strong magnetic field to make them permanently magnetic. [See this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet)

You can actually make your own permanent magnet by swiping a steel needle or nail a few times on a strong magnet. After this procedure, the steel becomes slightly magnetic, and can even act as a needle in a compass (try placing it on a piece of cork floating on water before and after magnetizing it).

Answer (score 4):

*Natural* magnets are produced by gradual alignment of magnetic domains in natural iron crystals with Earth's magnetic field, which happens to emanate from the core.

There is no connection between the refrigerator magnet and the earth's core. It produces a magnetic field all by itself. It was probably made in a factory rather than dug from the ground already magnetized.

A non-magnetic planet would not produce such strongly magnetic rocks. Mars, which does not have a global magnetic field, does nevertheless have large-scale magnetic domains. This means that you could find weakly magnetic rocks there.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand, the magnetic power of an ordinary permanent ferromagnet comes from and is maintained by the motion of molten iron in the Earth's core.

No, that's not correct at all. The ability of a permanent ferromagnet to attract (or repel) other objects is intrinsic to the magnet itself, and has nothing to do with the Earth's core or anything else outside the magnet. (Except the object being attracted or repelled, but only in the sense that some objects respond to magnetism and others don't.)

Answer (score 1):

A magnet isn't expending any energy to overcome gravity. That's like claiming your chair is expanding energy to hold you up against gravity. It doesn't require energy.
And your fridge magnet doesn't receive any energy from the earth, it would work equally well out in space.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not.
Magnetic forces are created because of the electron arrangement of the metal.
Not the planet's core or whatever.
Its the magnet, material, and the electron arrangement which matters.